# Auto-py-to-exe Import Error, cannot import brotli module, hidden import not working

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, exe, importerror, auto-py-to-exe

I'm trying to use AutoPy To Exe to convert a python script into an executable however the output EXE encounters an "ImportError" when trying to import the brotli module.

The section of code causing the error looks like this:

```
import requests
import string
try:
    import brotli
except(ImportError):
    print("oopsie\nLibrary not found")
import os
```

And outputs this

```
oopsie
Library not found
```

The Current Command I am using to convert it to an exe is this

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "brotli" --hidden-import "brotlipy"  "C:/Users/spudi/Desktop/nh scraper 3/scraper 3.py"
```

and the Output is this:

```
Running auto-py-to-exe v2.39.0
Building directory: C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib
Provided command: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import "brotli" --hidden-import "brotlipy"  "C:/Users/spudi/Desktop/nh scraper 3/scraper 3.py"
Recursion Limit is set to 5000
Executing: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --hidden-import brotli --hidden-import brotlipy C:/Users/spudi/Desktop/nh scraper 3/scraper 3.py --distpath C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\application --workpath C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\build --specpath C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib

612159 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.13.2
612160 INFO: Python: 3.11.5
612172 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
612188 INFO: wrote C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\scraper 3.spec
612209 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\spudi\\Desktop\\nh scraper 3']
612536 INFO: checking Analysis
612538 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-04.toc is non existent
612544 INFO: Reusing cached module dependency graph...
612564 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
612653 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-04.toc
612670 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
612700 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-appmodel-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
612753 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\spudi\Desktop\nh scraper 3\scraper 3.py
613723 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-charset_normalizer.py' from 'C:\\Users\\spudi\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
613840 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-certifi.py' from 'C:\\Users\\spudi\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\_pyinstaller_hooks_contrib\\hooks\\stdhooks'...
613916 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'brotlipy'
613928 ERROR: Hidden import 'brotlipy' not found
613943 INFO: Processing module hooks...
613959 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\spudi\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
614411 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\spudi\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
614424 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\spudi\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
614434 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
614447 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
614455 INFO: Including run-time hook 'C:\\Users\\spudi\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks\\rthooks\\pyi_rth_inspect.py'
614475 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
615251 INFO: Looking for eggs
615263 INFO: Using Python library C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\python311.dll
615264 INFO: Found binding redirects: 
[]
615279 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\build\scraper 3\warn-scraper 3.txt
615315 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\build\scraper 3\xref-scraper 3.html
615331 INFO: checking PYZ
615340 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-04.toc is non existent
615356 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\build\scraper 3\PYZ-04.pyz
615694 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\build\scraper 3\PYZ-04.pyz completed successfully.
615704 INFO: checking PKG
615712 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-04.toc is non existent
615728 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) scraper 3.pkg
617393 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) scraper 3.pkg completed successfully.
617396 INFO: Bootloader C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit-intel\run.exe
617404 INFO: checking EXE
617420 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-04.toc is non existent
617435 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-04.toc
617450 INFO: Copying bootloader EXE to C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\application\scraper 3.exe.notanexecutable
617492 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
617497 INFO: Copying icons from ['C:\\Users\\spudi\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python311\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
617533 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
617543 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
617559 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
617560 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
617574 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
617575 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
617589 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
617604 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
617609 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
617620 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
617635 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\spudi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpu22rypib\application\scraper 3.exe.notanexecutable
617674 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
617684 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
617704 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
618370 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-04.toc completed successfully.

Moving project to: C:\Users\spudi\Desktop\nh scraper 3\installer
Complete.
```

I have made sure brotli and brotlipy is installed using pip list, and when I try using hidden imports I find:

```
613928 ERROR: Hidden import 'brotlipy' not found
```

Any help is appreciated, sorry if I've made a simple error I am an amatuer.